# Book about a girl who had a space suit which came out of her pores

Tags: story-identification, books, space-opera

I am looking for an old space opera book I read; I can't remember the name. It has a squid-like creature who gives a girl a mission. Also, I remember that this girl had a space suit which came out of her pores; a fluid space/impact suit installed into her. Also her space ship had an AI which could manifest itself as a physical entity. I also remember a kind of lost ancient space ship that required the person piloting it to have a direct neural interface.

I read it on paperback some 7 to 8 yrs back.

Comment: This might be _[Excession](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excession)_ by Iain M. Banks, imperfectly remembered.

Comment: Possibly Stealing Light: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/40390/cant-remember-sci-fi-novel-with-loner-female-cargo-pilot-carrying-contraband-te/40464#40464

Comment: @timbp Agreed, this sounds like Stealing Light.

Comment: Possibly a book from Peter F. Hamilton: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Night's_Dawn_Trilogy - the books are 800-1000 pages each.

Answer (score 2):

So that there is an answer present, this matches up well with Gary Gibson's *[Stealing Light](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3607898-stealing-light)* as [posted by timbp](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/40390/cant-remember-sci-fi-novel-with-loner-female-cargo-pilot-carrying-contraband-te?noredirect=1&lq=1).

> **For a quarter of a million years, an alien race has been hiding a vast and terrible secret**
>
> In the 25th century, only the Shoal possess the secret of faster-than-light travel (FTL), giving them absolute control over all trade and exploration throughout the galaxy. Mankind has operated within their influence for two centuries, establishing a dozen human colony worlds scattered along Shoal trade routes. Dakota Merrick, while serving as a military pilot, has witnessed atrocities for which this alien race is responsible. Now piloting a civilian cargo ship, she is currently ferrying an exploration team to a star system containing a derelict starship. From its wreckage, her passengers hope to salvage a functioning FTL drive of mysteriously non-Shoal origin. But the Shoal are not yet ready to relinquish their monopoly over a technology they acquired through ancient genocide.

timbp posted an excerpt involving the space-suit within her:

> Convinced the life support was about to collapse, she activated her filmsuit. It spilled out of her skin from dozens of artificial pores, a flood of black ink that cocooned and protected her inside her own liquid spacesuit, growing transparent over her eyes so as to display the darkened space around her in infrared.